Is there a way to update LineAmountType in invoice using Xero api?
Issue: LineAmountType is not changing when I use POST api to update an invoices that is in 'DRAFT' status. Is it my mistake or XeroAPI mistake?
Procedure:
Post API: https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/invoices/0463f612-d64d-4ca6-94d9-b8fe69ead528
Body:
{
"Status": "DRAFT",
"LineAmountType": "Exclusive"
}
Response:


The error 400 is due to an error in the payload. Also, including the line item id keeps the line as it is, please can you remove the line item id and then try again.
You can see you logs at https://developer.xero.com/myapps at this will tell you the reason for the errors.
We recommend that you write your code to display any validation errors

Tried applying your suggestion, got 200 now but LineAmountType is not changing, you can check the updated snippet in question.

Please can you raise a case with Xero Support (https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support) and include the client id for your app, the time, date and timezone for the request and the log id (you can see this in url when looking at the log in the History section of the app record in developer.xero.com)
